# I am getting page unresponsive error when I am trying to export more than 1000 records in csv?

Tags: javascript, php, database, memory

I have my application built. I have more than 2000 records which I fetch as a report and those are visible on the front end. When I try to export the data into csv then either my page will stuck or will show page unresponsive error. CSV will be downloaded in either case but this issue is quite annoying.

How can it be handled at code level?

This is part of my code

```
$filename = $filename.''.time().'.csv';
$file = fopen($reportDir.'/'.$filename,"w");
fwrite($file,$transContent);
fclose($file);
```

I tried `fputcsv` as well. I alsoe have tried

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('opcache.enable', '0');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
```

I also tried to disable `Opcache` But Nothing working?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. Good Luck

```js
function download_csv(csv, filename) {
    var csvFile;
    var downloadLink;

    // CSV FILE
    csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});

    // Download link
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    // File name
    downloadLink.download = filename;

    // We have to create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

    // Make sure that the link is not displayed
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";

    // Add the link to your DOM
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    // Lanzamos
    downloadLink.click();
}

function export_table_to_csv(html, filename) {
    var csv = [];
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");
        
        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) 
            row.push(cols[j].innerText);
        
        csv.push(row.join(","));        
    }

    // Download CSV
    download_csv(csv.join("\n"), filename);
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var html = document.querySelector("table").outerHTML;
    export_table_to_csv(html, "table.csv");
});
```

```css
* {
    color: #2b2b2b;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
}

th {
    text-align: left;
    color: #4679bd;
}

tbody > tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #daeaff;
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>
    <tr><td>A</td><td>26</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td><td>19</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C</td><td>32</td></tr>
</table>
<button>Export HTML table to CSV file</button>
```

Comment: It will not enable you to download online but you can use it on your system to run it.